# Return a string value to the pass-in varibale from the argument in a function

Tags: java

I want the pass-in variable "aaa" to be returned the value from the argument of the function. I really need my argument in the function to be defined as String, and want whatever change of the argument in the function to be return to the pass-in variable.

How do I make this happen in Java? If anyone could help I will appreciate!

```
public class DeppDemo {
    private String aaa;

    public void abc(String aaa) {
        aaa = "123";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeppDemo demo = new DeppDemo();
        demo.abc(demo.aaa);
        System.out.println(demo.aaa);
    }
}
```

Comment: That example is ***much*** more complicated and misleading than it needs to be. Why have the field and argument have the same name? Are you aware you're shadowing the field in `abc` with the argument?

Comment: yeah it's typo sorry, but what i really want is whatever the name of argument is, I want the variable aaa to recieve the value that is assigned to the argument of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it like this: `String` class in Java is *immutable*, and all parameters, including object references, are passed by value.

You can achieve the desired result in one of three ways:

- Return a new `String` from a method and re-assign it in the caller,
- Pass mutable `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`, and modify its content in place, or
- Pass an instance of `DeppDemo`, and add a setter for `aaa`.

Here are some examples:

```
public class DeppDemo {
    private String aaa;
    private StringBuilder bbb = new StringBuilder();

    public String abc() {
        return "123";
    }
    public void def(StringBuilder x) {
        x.setLength(0);
        x.append("123");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeppDemo demo = new DeppDemo();
        demo.aaa = demo.abc(); // Assign
        demo.def(demo.bbb);    // Mutate
        System.out.println(demo.aaa);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my actual code, I cannot change the number of the argument in the function or change the return type of the function because in fact I use my java code to access the external library written in C. but I really need the pass-in variable to recieve the value from the function because the return type of the function is defined as boolean, which I have no right to change it.(the dll I access has no source code provided)

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you're asking, but it *sounds* like you're trying to change the content of a variable passed into a function. If so, you **can't** in Java. Java doesn't do pass-by-reference.

Instead, you pass in an object or array, and modify the state of that object or array.

```
public class DeppDemo {

    public void abc(String[] aaa) {
        aaa[0] = "123";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] target = new String[1];
        DeppDemo demo = new DeppDemo();
        demo.abc(target);
        System.out.println(target[0]);
    }
}
```

But if you're asking how to update the `aaa` *field* using the `aaa` *argument*, then you need to qualify your reference to the field using `this.`, since you've used the same name for both. Or change the name of the argument.

```
public class DeppDemo {
    private String aaa;

    public void abc(String aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeppDemo demo = new DeppDemo();
        demo.abc("New value");
        System.out.println(demo.aaa);
   }
}
```

Comment: In my actual code, I cannot change the number of the argument in the function or change the return type of the function because in fact I use my java code to access the external library written in C. but I really need the pass-in variable to recieve the value from the function because the return type of the function is defined as boolean, which I have no right to change it.(the dll I access has no source code provided)

Comment: @Ron: You simply cannot do that in Java, full stop. Java simply does not have pass-by-reference semantics, which is what you would need to pass a reference to variable.